# Gegenteil von Abkürzung

Tags: abbreviation, antonym

Ich stehe gerade auf dem Schlauch bei der Suche nach dem richtigen Begriff:

> "usw." ist die **Abkürzung** von "und so weiter".
>
> "und so weiter" ist der/die/das **???** von "usw."

(Expansion? Vollversion? Verlängerung? Ausschreibung? ...)

Ich hatte die Hoffnung, dass z.B. der Wikipedia-Artikel zum Thema Abkürzung den gesuchten Begriff zufällig verwendet, wurde da aber leider nicht fündig ...

Comment: I thought for sure someone would say "the opposite of abbreviation is the German Language"! ;)

Comment: "Vollform" (siehe Loongs Antwort) hat seit Februar d.J. ein Lemma in der deutschen Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vollform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In verschiedenen Bänden des Duden findet man vereinzelt den Begriff ***Vollform***.

> Als Stichworteinträge erscheinen auch gängige Abkürzungen und Kurzwörter, bei denen zumindest die Vollform, oft aber auch weitere Angaben zu Gebrauch und Bedeutung zu finden sind.
>
> Bei Kürzungen aus der Vollform von Wörtern unterscheidet man Abkürzungen und Kurzwörter.

In deutschen Normen des DIN wird der gesuchte Begriff gewöhnlich (z. B. mit ***vollständig*** oder ***ungekürzt***) umschrieben.

> Wenn das Dokument keine Liste der verwendeten Abkürzungen enthält (…), muss beim ersten Auftreten einer Abkürzung die vollständige Benennung und dahinter in Klammern die Abkürzung angegeben werden.
>
> Abkürzungen, die im vollen Wortlaut des ungekürzten Wortes gesprochen werden, erhalten in der Regel einen Punkt.

Comment: +1. "Vollform" findet man auch in der Produktbeschreibung von "Duden - Das Wörterbuch der Abkürzungen" im Duden-Shop.

Answer (score 12):

> **ausgeschrieben**

Ich befürchte, dass kein Substantiv existiert.

> "Und so weiter" ist "usw." ausgeschrieben.
>
> AKW ausgeschrieben heißt Atomkraftwerk.
>
> Was heißt HIV ausgeschrieben?

Benötigen wir unbedingt ein Substantiv, gibt es ein paar Möglichkeiten:

> die ausgeschriebene Form
>
> das Ausgeschriebene
>
> ~die Bedeutung (*Was ist die Bedeutung von AKW?* - wobei hier nicht ganz klar ist, ob jemand nach der ausgeschriebenen Form fragt oder tatsächlich nach der Bedeutung des abgekürzten Begriffes)

Comment: +1 für "ausgeschriebene Form"

Answer (score 7):

Wie wäre es mit

> **Langform**

für die ausgeschriebene Abkürzung/*Kurzform*?