# Was nennt man die ausgeschriebenen Vollformen für ein Akronym?

Tags: abbreviation

Ein Akronym setzt sich bekanntlich aus den Anfangsbuchstaben von Wörtern zusammen. Wie nennt man dabei die ausgeschriebenen Vollformen der Wörter?

Comment: Wir hätten auch erst suchen können: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29488/gegenteil-von-abk%C3%BCrzung

Answer (score 4):

Die Frage enthält bereits die Antwort: **Vollform**.

**Vollform** ist ein relationaler Begriff: *Personenkraftwagen* ist die Vollform von *PKW*.

**Abkürzung** ist der **konverse** Begriff: *PKW* ist die Abkürzung von *Personenkraftwagen*.

Das typische Beispiel für konverse Relationen sind Verwandtschaftsbezeichnungen: *Onkel/Tante* – *Neffe/Nichte* etc.

Ein **Kurzwort** ist eine Abkürzung, die auch als solche gesprochen wird. Demnach ist *Hr.* kein Kurzwort, da es wie die Vollform *Herr* gesprochen wird; *PKW* [ˈpeːkaːveː] dagegen schon.

Ein Auszug aus einem Text, in dem diese Begriffe tatsächlich verwendet werden:

> Ein Kurzwort ist nur dann ein Kurzwort, wenn ihm eine Vollform zugeordnet werden kann. Die Relation Vollform-Kurzform gilt als quasi synchron, oder — mit anderen Worten — Kurzformen sind lexikalische Varianten von Vollformen. Das bedeutet,
>   daß lexikalische Konstrukte, die zwar Kürzungen aufweisen, denen aber keine
>   Vollform zur Seite steht, keine Kurzwörter sind.
>
> Das bedeutet auch, daß Kurzwörter nicht das Ergebnis von diachronem
>   Lautwandel sind. Das aus **hegizussa* entstandene nhd. Wort *Hexe* ist kein
>   Kurzwort, weil es keine synchrone Vollform neben sich hat; die zweifellos beobachtbare Kürzung von **hegizussa* zu Hexe ist das Ergebnis jahrhundertelanger Lautwandlungen.

Albrecht Greule, Reduktion als Wortbildungsprozeß der deutschen Sprache, in: *Brünner Beiträge zur Germanistik und Nordistik* X, 1996, S. 7–19, [Link](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/106020/1_BrunnerBeitratgeGermanistikNordistik_10-1996-1_2.pdf).

Comment: Du hast zwar im Praktischen recht. Aber wenn man es genau nimmt, sollte das *Gegenteil* einer Abkürzung (nämlich einer *kürzeren* Fassung eines Begriffs gemessen an der Grundform) eigentlich eine ***Auflängung*** sein, nämlich eine gemessen an der Grundform noch längere Form. Dass das so gut wie nicht existiert... nun gut. Darum hast du ja praktisch recht.

Comment: PS: Möglicherweise könnte man doch Ansätze für die Existenz der von mir oben eingeführten *Auflängungen* finden: Nehmen wir das Begriffspaar *Verkehrsampel / Lichtzeichenanlage*. Sie bezeichnen dasselbe Ding. Das Wort *Lichtzeichenanlage* ist an sich komplett überflüssig. Es wurde nur erfunden, um bestimmte bürokratische Bedürfnisse zu erfüllen, die auf der soziologischen, nicht der inhaltlichen Ebene liegen. Ähnlich besteht für Abkürzungen kein inhaltlicher Bedarf, aber die Bequemlichkeit der Sprecher legt eine Abkürzung nahe. Andere Fälle von Auflängung sind durch Höflichkeit begründet.

Comment: Zivilisatorischer Fortschritt bedeutet steigenden Benennungsbedarf. Ich sehe grundsätzlich keinen Mutwillen. Ein Beispiel aus [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dachentw%C3%A4sserung): *Es gibt zwei Arten der Dachentwässerung, die beide nach dem Prinzip der Schwerkraftentwässerung funktionieren: die Freispiegelentwässerung (auch Freigefälleentwässerung genannt), bei der das Rohrleitungssystem im Gefälle verlegt wird und die Unterdruckentwässerung.*